# End position of damped harmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

It's a question I haven't thought of. It's evidence the solution of damped harmonic oscillation can be represented by:

$$x(t) = e^{\textstyle -\delta\,t}\,\left[c_1\,\cos(\omega_e\,t)+c_2\,\sin(\omega_e\,t)\right]$$

> **where the initial ODE was $$0 = \ddot{x} + \beta\,\dot{x}+m\,{\omega_0}^2$$ as well as $\delta = \frac{\beta}{2\,m}$ plus $\omega_e = \sqrt{{\omega_0}^2-\delta^2}$**

with starting conditions $x(0) = x_0$ and $\dot{x}(0) = 0$ this further specifies to:

$$x(t) = e^{\textstyle -\delta\,t}\,\left[x_0\,\cos(\omega_t\,t)+\dfrac{\delta\,x_0}{\omega_e}\,\sin(\omega_t\,t)\right]$$

This is all open access, but I've found no one addressing ending conditions.

So I ask myself can a value $x_{\textstyle t = \infty}$ be determined? I'm stunting since $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)$ seems not probable.

Comment: The first factor goes to zero, the second is bounded. How would you enforce anything other than the zero condition at infinity? The reverse problem is impossible to solve, as any solution converges to zero.

Comment: Right, totally forgot there's a minus within the exponent. So basically because of $0$ will be the limit, there can be an offset added: $x(t) = \textsf{offset} + e^{\textstyle - \delta \,t}\,\cdots$ where the function will converge to. Additively $x(0) = x_0 - \textsf{offset}$ should be altered properly.

Comment: Not with a linear homogeneous equation. To get an equilibrium other than zero you need to adjust the inhomogeneity.